# Scalar value which minimises the difference between two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I have an optimisation problem which involves minimising the relative difference between two vectors, I'll call them $x_T$ (target) and $x_A$ (achieved). I'm interested in the relative difference rather than the total difference and each value in the vector needs to be assigned a weight $a_i$, so each element of the vector $d$ for which I'm trying to minimise the L2 norm looks like this:

$$d_i=a_i\left(\frac{x_{Ti}-x_{Ai}}{x_{Ti}}\right)$$

I'm actually able to scale $x_A$ so really I'd like to know the value of $b$ which will minimise the L2 norm of d:

$$d_i=a_i\left(\frac{x_{Ti}-bx_{Ai}}{x_{Ti}}\right)$$

Hopefully I've phrased this in an understandable way - I know plenty of numerical methods which will let me solve this in steps but I feel like there must be a simple and easy way to solve it directly!

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I have something that works! I came across this paper during my searches:

[Least Squares Percentage Regression](http://uhra.herts.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/2299/965/S64.pdf)

The matrix $D$ described in the paper is a matrix with $1/x_{Ti}$ on the diagonal and zeros elsewhere. They referred to it as a 'weighting matrix' so I figured I can incorporate my weights as well like this: $a_i/x_{Ti}$. The value $b$ to which I referred (coincidentally also called $b$ in the paper) can then be found using the method they describe.

Seems to work! Figured I'd post an answer in case anyone runs into the same problem.